# JSON data not uploading to database

Tags: json, node.js, database, cloudant, nosql

I'm using the IBM Cloudant NoSQL database, and I'm trying to upload a document to it in Node.js. The document (.xlsx) is first read in and converted to json:

```
xlsxj({

    input: "testdata/WHO_NREVSS.xlsx",
    output: "testdata/WHO_NREVSS.json"

      }, function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
      console.error(err);
    }else {

      // Read the file and send to the callback
      fs.readFile('./testdata/WHO_NREVSS.json', handleFile)

      //The callback function
      function handleFile(err, data) {
          if (err) throw err
          else{
            //data = data.replace( "\"", '\\"');
            obj = JSON.parse(data);
```

So far it works fine. When I console.log obj, I get an array full of json data:

```
[
{
  "H3N2v": "0",
  "REGION TYPE": "Census Regions",
  "REGION": "New England",
  "YEAR": "2007",
  "WEEK": "40",
  "timeline": "2007-40",
  "TOTAL SPECIMENS": "115",
  "PERCENT POSITIVE": "0",
  "A (H1)": "0",
  "A (Unable to Subtype)": "0",
  "A (H3)": "0",
  "2009 H1N1": "0",
  "A (Subtyping not Performed)": "0",
  "B": "0"
},...
]
```

Now, when I want to insert this array in a document on Cloudant, which looks like this...:

```
testdb.insert({"_id": "statistic", "data":obj}, function(error, result){
  if(error) {
    console.error(error);
  }else {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
  }
})
```

... I just get a document with "_id" and "_rev" as a result, but the key "data" and the value "obj" don't appear at all. Why is that the case? 
When I manually (by copy - paste) insert the array in cloudant, it works fine.

Update 1:
When using "data" from the callback function handleFile, I actually get a result in the database, but it looks like this:

```
"data": [
91,
123,
34,
72,
51,
78,
...
]
```

While it should not. Logging it gives me the result "Buffer 5b 7b 22 48 33 ... "

**SOLUTION**

The problem was solved by moving the whole 'insert' part in the callback function. Now it works the way it should work. The final code:

```
  fs.readFile('./testdata/WHO_NREVSS.json', handleFile)
  // Write the callback function
  function handleFile(err, data) {
      if (err) throw err
      else{
        obj = JSON.parse(data);

        testdb.insert({"_id": "statistic", "data":obj}, function(error, result){
          if(error) {
            console.error(error);
          }else {
            console.log(obj);
          }
        })
```

Comment: Are you intending to save the entire excel document as a single JSON object? It may be too large.

Comment: The thing is, when I convert it into json and store it locally, it works. I fI copy paste the content of this json file into the database manually, it works too. Only when I try to do it via 'insert', it won't work and I don't know why.